# Iterate through ArrayList of instance's variable

Tags: java

I want to know how to iterate through the following Arraylist.

```
public class FruitHandler {

    private ArrayList<Fruits> fruit;
    private ArrayList<Integer> fruitUID= new ArrayList<>();

    public static FruitHandler getInstance() {
            return instance;
    }

    public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruitUID.add(fruit.getfruitUID());
        this.fruit.add(fruit);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to iterate through the fruitUID and return the instance of that fruit class that is stored in `ArrayList<Fruits> fruit` which matches my given UID.

Example, I have an `fruitUID = 10`, I want to have the reference of the instance of the fruit class that is stored in `ArrayList<Fruits> fruit` which have its `fruitUID = 10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a `Fruit` instance given a fruitUID then you probably want a `Map<Integer, Fruit>`.

You could also just have a list of `Fruit` instances and use a stream and a filter to find just the single instance with a specified fruitUID.

If you absolutely must use two lists, then you need find the index of the specified fruitUID and extract the `Fruit` from the other list at the same index.

**Edit:** If you want to use a map:

```
private Map<Integer, Fruits> fruits = new HashMap<>();

public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
    fruits.put(fruit.getfruitUID(), fruit);
}

public Fruit findFruit(Integer fruitUID) {
    return fruits.get(fruitUID);
}
```

Comment: I think I'm overthinking much, how to iterate through the map of fruits from external class? or no need to iterate? i just call findFruit and thats all.

Comment: @Emily, that's what's great about a Map.  No iterating.  It takes you right to the Fruit you're looking for. - I highly recommend you study up a bit on data structures, especially HashMaps.  They're one of the cornerstones of computing...a concept of optimizing data lookups that we all use every day.

Answer (score 1):

The solution point out by @Jason will make your problem much easier, but if you are in hurry and consider using a quick solution you can have the following code  (not good in term of performance

```
public class FruitHandler {

    private ArrayList<Fruits> fruit;
    private ArrayList<Integer> fruitUID= new ArrayList<>();

    public static FruitHandler getInstance() {
            return instance;
    }
    public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruitUID.add(fruit.getfruitUID());
        this.fruit.add(fruit);
    }
    public Fruit findFruitByFruitUID(Integer fruitUID){
             for(Fruit fr: fruit){
                     if(fr.getfruitUID()==fruitUID){
                      return fr;
                      }
             }
        return null;
         }
}
```